# Facebook SDK - Mobile Web "Getting Started" doesn't work

Tags: facebook

I create a new html file and input the code given in [Mobile Web Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#login)

I follow all the instructions in ["Getting Started"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/) section to login

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Facebook</title>
     <meta name="viewport" 
        content="initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <style>
  body.connected #login { display: none; }
  body.connected #logout { display: block; }
  body.not_connected #login { display: block; }
      body.not_connected #logout { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'blahblah, // App ID
      channelUrl :  '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<div id="login">
   <p><button onClick="loginUser();">Login</button></p>
 </div>
 <div id="logout">
   <p><button  onClick="FB.logout();">Logout</button></p>
 </div>

 <script>
   function loginUser() {    
     FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});     
     }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work 
i only change appID

do i miss something?

i follow and doesn't do anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should continue with the next steps in the tutorial to get functional results. It looks like you stopped halfway at the login step of the tutorial.

I also updated the domain info in the line under the appID line.

And make sure you test on a mobile browser or on desktop that you set the user agent. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#test for instructions.

I wasn't able to see my profile photo and my name and other things like friends names until I tried it on my iPhone.

Comment: Do i need to change channelUrl ? or i just leave it alone with default? i try it on mobile phone but still not working =(